# Samsung Drivers Won't Work When in Fastboot Mode

Tags: windows, drivers, android, bootloader, root

I have made the mistake of trying to root my phone. Which is fine, but it's a lot more complicated than I thought it was, but since I have asperger's, once I start something, I feel like I have to finish it.

I have a Samsung Galaxy S7 (SM-G930U) with Sprint. I've heard that these phones are EXTREMELY difficult to root. Some even call it impossible. But I can at least try.

I ended up getting tunneled down a endless loop of tasks to complete before I actually root my phone, for preparation. One of the things I must complete is I have to install a TWRP Recovery Image in case of failure. But in order to do that, I have to unblock the bootloader.

To do this, I am using Platform Tools, with includes ADB (Android Debugging Bridge), and Fastboot. I connect my phone to my PC via USB cable, open the CMD, and type:

```
 adb reboot bootloader
```

Once I do this, my phone reboots into the bootloader, just like it should. Normally, the next step I would take would be to type in:

```
 fastboot oem unlock
```

When I do this, I am left with the message:

```
 < waiting for any device >
```

I'm assuming that means that it's not detecting my phone at all. It's odd though, because it was able to detect my device perfectly fine whenever my phone was booted normally, but when I go into the bootloader, it doesn't detect my phone anymore.

After hours of searching around the internet, I found that a potential problem could be the drivers of my phone that are installed on my PC.

Sure enough, if I open up the Device Manager, when in the bootloader, under Universal Serial Bus Controllers, I found the driver "SAMSUNG Mobile USB CDC Composite Device", with a little yellow arrow next to it on the icon.

If I double-click on the entry, in the "Device Status" box, it will say:

```
 This device cannot start. (Code 10)

 An invalid parameter was passed to a service or function.
```

Code 10 means that Windows is saying "There's a problem, but I don't know what." And well, I'm stumped by this.

The drivers work perfectly fine if I'm booted normally, which is why I'm confused.

If you're wondering, I using Windows 10.

Comment: You'll probably find a more specifically knowledgeable community for this question over in the Samsung Galaxy S7 forums on XDA Developers. Most of the rooting unlocking and modding community ends up there at some point.

Comment: I'll check it out then. I've seen the community on multiple occasions, I just didn't wanna have to go through the pain of making an account and all of that. But if that is what I must do, then I will. Thanks!

Comment: Still not fixed?